# <module 'myblog.urls' from 'path\\to\\python\\file\\urls.py'>' is not a callable or a dot-notation path

Tags: python, django

I have this code in one file called urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.contrib import admin
from myblog import urls

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'', urls),
]
```

Im trying to redirect to another file in a module called myblog which contains another file called urls.py with the following code:

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.post_list, name='post_list'),
]
```

my views file which contains post_list method is as follows:

```
from django.shortcuts import render

def post_list(request):
    return render(request,'myblog/post_list.html', {})
```

The result is that i keep getting the following error message:

> module 'myblog.urls' from 'path\to\python\file\urls.py' is not a callable or a dot-notation path

Can anyone please explain to me where i am getting it wrong. I am new to django and python and i am using a tutorial from DjangoGirls.com. They use Django 1.8 and i have Django 1.9 installed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking at the [tutorial](http://tutorial.djangogirls.org/en/django_urls/index.html#your-first-django-url), uou can see that you have forgotten to use `include`.

First you have to add the import

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
```

Then change the url pattern to:

```
url(r'', include('blog.urls')),
```

Be careful that you are using the correct module name - you have `myblog`, but the tutorial has `blog`.

Comment: Using strings in `include` is fine, it's using strings for views, (e.g. `url(r'blog', 'myblog.view_posts'),`) which is deprecated. The [Django 1.9 tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/intro/tutorial01/#write-your-first-view) still uses strings for include.

Comment: Right ok sure, (I've already gone through the process of removing strings everywhere so I forgot which was the actual warnings...)

Comment: include gives me an saying include is not defined

Comment: It sounds like you've missed out the import for include. I've added it to the answer above.

Answer (score 2):

You need to [`include`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/urls/#include) the urls.py to link them

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'', include(urls, namespace='MyOtherapp')),
]
```

Note: I've also added a namespace here, its not required, it just helps when your using the `url` template tag.

Comment: If you're following the tutorial, I wouldn't use a namespace for now, it might cause confusion when using the url tag later.

Comment: @Alasdair - Agreed, hence why I haven't gone into detail :)

Comment: but when i use include, i get another error message which says include is not defined

Comment: @Tatenda - Yes you need to import it `from django.conf.urls import include`